# What is the meaning and purpose of this assignment in a type declaration in this example?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code example:

```
export type DataViewProps = {
  width: number, // in px
  height: number, // in px
  data: Data,
};

export class DataView<P extends DataViewProps = DataViewProps>
    extends React.Component<P> {
```

What is the meaning of this assignment `<P extends DataViewProps = DataViewProps>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of this assignment `<P extends DataViewProps = DataViewProps>`

The assigment portion `= DataViewProps` means that `P` resolves to `DataViewProps` if its not specified. Its called default type argument.

E.g.

```
const foo = new DataView<Something>(); // P is Something
const bar = new DataView(); // P is DataViewProps
```